# What is the best way to display relationship data using a foreach loop within Laravel Nova?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have 3 tables: questions, user and userAnswer. I want to display all answers that for each user on the questions page. the the user table is the pivot. one question has many users, has many answers.

```
Stack::make('Answers', [
                function ($userId) {
                    $getAnswers = \App\Models\userAnswer::where('id', $userId)->get();
                    $combinedAnswers = '';
                    foreach ($getAnswers as $getAnswer) {
                        $combinedAnswers .= $getAnswer->answer;
                    }
                    return $combinedAnswers;
                },
            ]),
```

How do i display this information on the question page in nova?

Ideally i'd also wrap a foreach loop for each question. At the moment, i don't need to be able to update the fields, just display them. what is the best way to achieve this in nova? Thanks,

Comment: Why do you have the pivot table, since that seems irrelevant if you just give the answer a `user_id`? With that you could also specify a many to many relation and call `User::with('answers')->get();` and get the answers per user.

Comment: hi @geertjanknapen, thanks, i guess my main issue, is how do i display that information on the questionnaire page within nova?

Comment: Well you should make sure this works before going there.